# How to catch the terminal output?

Tags: python

I'm working on https://github.com/JsBergbau/MiTemperature2 with raspberry pi 3 model b. It's working properly on its own infinite loop but I am not able to catch the output from the terminal. How can I reach to output by using python?

Here is the part of printing:

```
    measurement_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(measurement.timestamp)
    print(measurement_time)
    humidity=int.from_bytes(data[2:3],byteorder='little')
    print("Temperature: " + str(temp))
    print("Humidity: " + str(humidity))
    voltage=int.from_bytes(data[3:5],byteorder='little') / 1000.
    print("Battery voltage:",voltage,"V")
    measurement.temperature = temp
    measurement.humidity = humidity
    measurement.voltage = voltage
    measurement.sensorname = args.name
    batteryLevel = min(int(round((voltage - 2.1),2) * 100), 100) #3.1 or above --> 100% 2.1 --> 0 %
    measurement.battery = batteryLevel
    print("Battery level:",batteryLevel)
    measurement_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(measurement.timestamp)
```

Here is the script I run on terminal:

```
python3 LYWSD03MMC.py -d AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
```

And here is the output:

```
2021-08-05 11:21:24
Temperature: 24.79
Humidity: 47
Battery voltage: 3.092 V
Battery level: 99
```

here is the run command and sample output, thanks for helps, best regards.

Comment: Please don't post code as images...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you really want to run `LYWSD03MMC.py` as a subprocess, you can certainly do `proc = subprocess.Popen(..., stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, then read `proc.stdout` line-per-line and parse the data. However, it would be much better to take that code and turn it into a library you can use. It shouldn't be very hard.

Comment: @mx0 what I'm trying to do is taking output program produce from terminal and using independently in another script

Answer (score 1):

Change your code so it `return`s the information instead of just `print`ing it. If you have code which looks like

```py
something = some_function_call(123)
print(something)
other_one = different_function("some data here?").strip()
print(other_one)
```

probably refactor to

```py
def get_something(number):
    return some_function_call(number)

def get_other_one():
    return different_function("some data here?").strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_something(123))
    print(get_other_one())
```

Now, you can create additional code which retrieves these values without printing them, and does whatever it wants with them. Put them on a web site? Upload them to a database? Rot13 encrypt them and send an email to Bill Gates? Your imagination is the limit.

How exactly you design your code is a broad topic where many books have been written, and more will be.  A common arrangement is to make sure the useful parts are in modular functions which do one thing only (ideally without any side effects) so you can `import` this code and use it from other programs. (That's why the `if __name__` part is useful. It makes sure code inside the block doesn't run when you `import` this file.)

Comment: The library linked on GitHub is not OP's own code. Additionally, if you look at the linked code, it's... not quite straightforward to "just make it return" things, since it's not designed very well at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a closer look at the code? There is a callback option. This is the easiest way to get values from this script. Or is this question more academically on how to capture python output?

If not, that should help you:

Documentation where callback is described:
https://github.com/JsBergbau/MiTemperature2#callback-for-processing-the-data

Accessing the single values:
In sendToInflux.sh https://github.com/JsBergbau/MiTemperature2/blob/master/sendToInflux.sh is an example in which argument are the values like temperature and so on.

Or when using sendToFile.sh it gives line by line
`sensorname,temperature,humidity,voltage,humidityCalibrated,timestamp MySensor 20.61 54 2.944 49 1582120122`

That data should be easy to process by python or awk.

Comment: the callback option does not work correctly, maybe I was not able to but it did not as a result..

Comment: Did you make the callback executable? I'm using this script for a while and callback works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

add commandline

```
2>&1 | tee result.txt
```

it can save command line output

Comment: using this or >blabla.txt or >>blabla.txt doesn't matter, they do not work

Comment: Of course they work, they save the output to a file. If that's not what you want, you need to make sure your question is more specific.

Comment: Oh, you might need to add an `-u` option to see the output if you are impatient, like it says at the top of the script you link to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a command from python you can use [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to get the returning output from the terminal. Don't work if the called script runs forever.

Like this:

```
output = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, 'LYWSD03MMC.py', '-d', 'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF']).decode()
```

Comment: The script runs in an infinite loop, so this will never return.

Comment: @AKX Ye, that is correct, subprocess.check_output wont work if the LYWSD03MMC.py runs in an infinite loop